# Como obter um arquivo armazenado com nodejs e multer?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, multer

Na API, em NodeJS, que estou fazendo, o usuário envia a imagem para a API e, utilizando o multer, a imagem é armazenada. Todos os tutoriais que vi para essa situação, o Node está utilizando um preprocessador como jade, ejs, handlebars etc. Mas no meu caso, a front é feito em Vuejs. Então, como fazer para a API "mostrar" a imagem pesquisada? Se tento acessar `localhost:3000/api/company/public/minha-imagem.jgp` o seguinte erro aparece `Cannot GET /api/company/public/minha-imagem.jpg`.

Comment: Queres mostrar uma imagem que o cliente envie ou vai enviar para o servidor, é isso? e porque não fazer tudo no lado do cliente em vêz de enviar para o servidor e depois de volta?

Comment: Essa imagem é a imagem do produto. Não tenho como armazenar no front a imagem, sendo que o nome dela também precisa ser gravado no banco. Por isso a necessidade de enviar para o servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Solução. No meu `app.js`, eu inseri `app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist')));`